# How to set a overlay div loading image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show a loading image as overlay div in my ajax search time.

my code

```
<script>
function showHint(str) {
  if (str.length==0) { 
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","search_result.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>


<input name="keyword" id="keyword" type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)""/>
```

result show in this table

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <table class="openings" id="result">

    </table>
</div>
```

my current code correctly show in this table but only need to add a overlay loading.

Also when i search any thing then it show correctly but after typing if i delete search keyword from box then result area will be blank.

Comment: Any reason this is tagged with `jQuery`?

Comment: Off topic: You have added the tag jQuery. If you are using jQuery why use vanilla xmlhttp instead of `$.get()`?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do by using plain javascript and CSS is the following:

```
**[JAVASCRIPT]**
<script type="text/javascript">

function showLoadingImage(visible){
   document.getElementById("loader").style.visibility = visible ? "visible" : "hidden";
}

function showHint(str) {
  if (str.length==0) { 
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }

  showLoadingImage(true);

  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      showLoadingImage(false);
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","search_result.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

**CSS**
<style type="text/css">
    #loader{
       position:fixed;
       width:100%;
       height:100%;
       display:table;
       visibility:hidden;
       background-color: rgba(0,0,0.6);
    }

    #loader .inner{
       display: table-cell;
       vertical-align:middle;
    }
</style>

**[HTML]**
<div id="loader">
   <div class="inner">
      <img src="loader.gif">
   </div>
</div>
```

On the above example when you execute the "showHint" function the loader div is shown, covers the screen and your loader image is shown in the middle of the screen. Of course you can change the div#loader background color and generally configure it as you wish.